# Find reason behind BSOD resource_not_owned

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I've an HP EliteBook 850 G7 with Windows 10 1909 (18363.1916), it's around 1.5 year old.

In the past couple of months I started to get BSOD 1-2 times a month.

- The pc is managed by my company, I can't recall if any major updated were installed when it started to happen.
- Trying to solve the issue I made sure all my drivers are up to date, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.
- I noticed that time to time "system interrupts" has very high CPU usage. I don't know whether it's related to the problem.
- after last BSOD today, analyzing minidump with windbg I got below results. Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to get any clue for solution.

[image]

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22473.1005 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\uxxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\_TEMP\_temp\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 18362 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`35000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`35445ed0
Debug session time: Wed Nov 17 11:07:07.506 2021 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 5 days 0:26:59.278
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
........................................................
Loading User Symbols
................................................................
................................................................
...................................
Loading unloaded module list
......................................................................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff800`351c44c0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:ffffd30c`3522ebf0=00000000000000e3
5: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

RESOURCE_NOT_OWNED (e3)
A thread tried to release a resource it did not own.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff86812f15cd10, Address of resource
Arg2: ffff86812fb93080, Address of thread
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Address of owner table if there is one
Arg4: 0000000000000002

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 14921

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 36271

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 6061

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 627975

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 93

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: 19h1_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-03-18T12:02:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.18362.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

BUGCHECK_CODE:  e3

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff86812f15cd10

BUGCHECK_P2: ffff86812fb93080

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 2

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  OneDrive.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd30c`3522ebe8 fffff800`351f7aa1     : 00000000`000000e3 ffff8681`2f15cd10 ffff8681`2fb93080 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd30c`3522ebf0 fffff800`3503b85a     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8681`6e1c7758 ffffd30c`00000000 : nt!ExpReleaseResourceSharedForThreadLite+0x1bc171
ffffd30c`3522eca0 fffff800`35ffa1cd     : ffffd30c`3522ee20 ffff8681`6e1c7758 01880000`00008d5f 00000000`00003200 : nt!ExReleaseResourceLite+0xea
ffffd30c`3522ed00 fffff800`3600b9ba     : ffff8681`3bdf34c0 ffff8681`6e1c7758 ffffd30c`3522ef01 ffff9c00`643194f8 : cldflt!CldHsmHydratePlaceholder+0xacd
ffffd30c`3522ee70 fffff800`3600b112     : ffff8681`6e1c7700 ffff8681`81a4ba00 ffff8681`2f15cc01 fffff800`3602a000 : cldflt!HsmiRecallInitiateHydration+0x7d6
ffffd30c`3522f000 fffff800`3600b1d9     : fffff800`3600b180 ffff8681`6e1c7758 00000000`00000000 fffff800`3503b86f : cldflt!HsmiRecallPostProcessHydration+0x24a
ffffd30c`3522f090 fffff800`35ff527d     : fffff800`3600b180 00000000`00000000 fffff800`3600b180 fffff800`35fc3ae7 : cldflt!HsmiRecallHydrationCompletionCallback+0x59
ffffd30c`3522f0c0 fffff800`35ff5d10     : ffff9c00`6645be40 ffff9c00`643194a0 ffff9c00`820c6760 00000000`00000000 : cldflt!CldiStreamCompleteRequest+0x1f9
ffffd30c`3522f140 fffff800`35ff7ada     : ffffd30c`3522f300 01880000`00008d5f 00000000`00000000 ffffd30c`c000022d : cldflt!CldiStreamProcessPendingHydrationRequests+0x2a8
ffffd30c`3522f220 fffff800`35ff2118     : fffff800`35fdd000 ffff9c00`00000000 ffff9c00`6645be40 ffff9c00`00000160 : cldflt!CldStreamRestartHydration+0x20a
ffffd30c`3522f2c0 fffff800`35feb0a0     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd30c`3522f3a1 ffff9c00`504bdc60 ffff9c00`4c787780 : cldflt!CldSyncRestartHydration+0x214
ffffd30c`3522f330 fffff800`35fec585     : ffff9c00`504bdc60 0000025a`9ea0eea0 01d7d7a9`5161575d 00000000`00000000 : cldflt!CldiPortProcessRestartHydration+0x724
ffffd30c`3522f400 fffff800`35fedb5a     : 7fffffff`ffffffff 0000025a`9ea0eea0 00000000`00000000 ffff9c00`6645bd01 : cldflt!CldiPortProcessTransfer+0x2f1
ffffd30c`3522f4a0 fffff800`345cae6b     : ffff9c00`504bdc60 0000025a`a02b9cd0 ffffd30c`00000270 00000000`00000000 : cldflt!CldiPortNotifyMessage+0xa4a
ffffd30c`3522f590 fffff800`345fbe14     : ffffd30c`3522f6a0 00000000`00000001 ffff8681`5b212350 fffff800`350b1a7e : FLTMGR!FltpFilterMessage+0xdb
ffffd30c`3522f5f0 fffff800`345fbed2     : ffff8681`5b212420 0000025a`a02b9cd0 00000000`00000000 ffff9c00`45a16a20 : FLTMGR!FltpMsgDeviceControl+0x128
ffffd30c`3522f650 fffff800`345c238f     : ffff8681`227cd4c0 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 fffff800`355fb415 : FLTMGR!FltpMsgDispatch+0xa2
ffffd30c`3522f6c0 fffff800`350373b9     : ffff8681`5b212350 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000270 : FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0xef
ffffd30c`3522f720 fffff800`355f30e5     : ffff8681`5b212350 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8681`3a32c4c0 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x59
ffffd30c`3522f760 fffff800`355f2ef0     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8681`3a32c4c0 ffffd30c`3522fa80 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1a5
ffffd30c`3522f800 fffff800`355f22c6     : 00007ffd`4d5c8898 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0xc10
ffffd30c`3522f920 fffff800`351d5d55     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
ffffd30c`3522f990 00007ffd`7c15cf84     : 00007ffd`707029b4 00000000`00000110 25333225`00000000 0000025a`a02b9cd0 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
000000c4`84efec58 00007ffd`707029b4     : 00000000`00000110 25333225`00000000 0000025a`a02b9cd0 00007ffd`4d5c8b46 : ntdll!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x14
000000c4`84efec60 00007ffd`70702301     : 0000025a`a02b9cd0 00000000`00000160 00000000`00000280 00000000`00000000 : FLTLIB!FilterpDeviceIoControl+0x128
000000c4`84efece0 00007ffd`4d5ca176     : 0000025a`a02b9cd0 000000c4`84efefe0 00000000`00000280 00000000`00000000 : FLTLIB!FilterSendMessage+0x31
000000c4`84efed30 00007ffd`4d5cb398     : 0000025a`9ea0eea0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : cldapi!CfpExecuteRestartHydration+0x12e
000000c4`84efeec0 00007ffc`ff81907e     : 000000f8`5a35940d 00000000`00000000 0000025a`9ea0eea0 00000000`00000001 : cldapi!CfExecute+0x1d8
000000c4`84efef60 000000f8`5a35940d     : 00000000`00000000 0000025a`9ea0eea0 00000000`00000001 0000025a`977428d0 : FileSyncFALWB!UploadTelemetry+0x163de
000000c4`84efef68 00000000`00000000     : 0000025a`9ea0eea0 00000000`00000001 0000025a`977428d0 00007ffc`ff80664f : 0x000000f8`5a35940d


SYMBOL_NAME:  cldflt!CldHsmHydratePlaceholder+acd

MODULE_NAME: cldflt

IMAGE_NAME:  cldflt.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  acd

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xE3_cldflt!CldHsmHydratePlaceholder

OS_VERSION:  10.0.18362.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {390ad588-5092-ab70-f1f7-9fbfe8e32ef3}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: The issue you describe was fixed with KB4517389. Have your company update your system. This issue isn’t something you can solve without an Administrator

Comment: You can also kill OneDrive.exe this issue was solved almost two and half years ago.

Comment: Update your computer to Windows 21H1 to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @harrymc it's a work pc, I need really strong argument to convince IT for upgrade.

Comment: Argument: Upgrade or replace my computer. (Not saying that the upgrade is sure to solve the problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the past couple of months I started to get BSOD 1-2 times a month.

Your issue is caused by OneDrive and still having an unsupported version of Windows 10 installed on your system. The simplest solution is to install the last update release for 1903. If you are unable to update your system to a supported release, a workaround is to exit OneDrive.exe and/or disable Auto-save within Office documents and disable On-Demand files within OneDrive.

It was reported that [KB4517389](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/anyone-else-seeing-bsod-issues-in-cldfltsys-after/e43b0303-6787-48b5-99cc-aeddd740300e?page=1&auth=1) is the cause of this issue.

Source: [OneDrive's cldflt.sys causing Win 10 BSOD SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2237262-onedrive-s-cldflt-sys-causing-win-10-bsod-system_service_exception)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ramhound! Actually I've Windows 10 1909 (18363.1916) and mentioned fix is not installed. Which version shall I update to? I use autosave heavily, disabling it is not an option.

Comment: Windows 21H1 ..

Comment: @MátéJuhász - You don't upgrade anything.  Your company, who manages your updates, will have to manage it.  `KB4517389` was released years before `18363.1916` was released and contains the fix.  If the problem is still happening then it was never patched for 1903 or 1909.